# Robotframework threads

Tags: robotframework

Is there any way you can start two actions in Robotframework. I'm trying to run a process that will run continuously and then make other actions without stopping the first process. The problem is that RF is waiting the first process to finish, then proceed with other actions. well, problem is the first process is not going to stop. Any advice?

Thanks, 
Stell

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this with the [Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) library. It lets you run programs in the background.

In my open source project [rfhub](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-hub), the acceptance test suite has a suite setup that starts the hub in the background.

Here's the keyword that starts the hub:

```
*** Keywords ***
| Start rfhub
| | [Arguments] | ${PORT}
| | [Documentation]
| | ... | Starts rfhub on the port given in the variable ${PORT}
| | ... | As a side effect this creates a suite variable named ${rfhub process},
| | ... | which is used by the 'Stop rfhub' keyword.
| | 
| | ${rfhub process}= | Start process | python | -m | rfhub | --port | ${PORT}
| | Set suite variable | ${rfhub process}
| | Wait until keyword succeeds | 20 seconds | 1 second
| | ... | Verify URL is reachable | /ping
```

Comment: Ok i forgot to mention that the first process is going to log some things continuously(and i want those things displyed on the console in real time).

Comment: You can possibly hack something together using process, but proper threading support has been removed from robotframework as it wasn't really used and was supposedly quite buggy. 

Or you could extend robot framework yourself and create a new keyword in python, and there use threads that way.

There is also this robotframework library that I think supports threading.
https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot